# PineScript - How to plot a line in upper graph (MA) or lower graph (RSI)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Is there a different way to plot a line in upper graph (like MA indicator) or in lower graph (like RSI indicator) because I can not see any difference in the code.

Will it be possible to have an indicator with plotting both graphs (up and down)?

Upper graph like MA

[image]

```
//@version=4
study(title="Moving Average", shorttitle="MA", overlay=true, resolution="")
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = sma(src, len)
plot(out, color=color.blue, title="MA", offset=offset)
```

Lower graph like RSI

[image]

```
//@version=4
study(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(band1, band0, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `study()` there is the `overlay` parameter. Using `overlay = true` places the indicator in the main pane and `overlay = false` into a sub pane like RSI.

You can only assign the indicator/script to a single pane, so no, you can't plot on both.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hline function to draw horizontal lines also line.new. If you want to plot on both top and bottom screens then you need to add code in both top and bottom.